# How do I find out maximum number of visitors at one time from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm not sure if this is even possible in Google Analytics. Is there a way to find out the maximum number of visitors that visited a site within a time period of one minute, or one hour? Or is the data only available per day.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like by the hour is available.

**Current version:**

Under Visitors -> Visitor Trending -> Visits

Click on the clock to the right of Graph by (under date range).

**New version:**

Visitors -> Overview -> Graph by (on right, under date) -> Hour

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and this is now available

> Public Beta is now available. Sign-up to be whitelisted.
>   http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-analytics-launches-real-time-api.html
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @andrewloft I think this is trying to answer the question of "how many visitors are there at the current time" which is a possible interpretation of the question.